# How can I pass a object to an instantiated object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a game where there is a turret shooting down objects, and only if they are in range... at least that is the thought.

Right now I'm able to detect the object distance, and if it is close enough the turret will fire a bullet:

```
            if( distanceToTarget < 10 )
            {
                Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, new Quaternion());
            }
```

The only problem is that the Bullet has no target. On the script (C#) of the Bullet i have defined a `public GameObject Target` that should hold the target. But how can I set this? Because when I instantiate the bullet, i know the target. Regularly I would set it straight forward, something like `Bullet.Target = target`, but I'm new to Unity and can't see how to set properties of a game object I Instantiate.
The script of the Bullet would then check if the target exists, ifnot destroy it self, ifso travel to target :)

But how can I set it's target?

Comment: y dont you just shoot the bullet to the position of the enemy

Answer (score 1):

This Instantiate function returns the instantiate object.
All you need to do is:

```
if( distanceToTarget < 10 )
    {
        GameObject obj = (GameObject) Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, new Quaternion());
        obj.GetComponent<Bullet>().Target = target;
    }
```

Comment: 'Bullet' (GameObject) is the variable where i store a prefab of 'bullet'. 'bullet' prefab has a script with the public GameObject Target. I can't seem to set Target?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the cast in the end of sentence. This is all I can do ;/

Comment: Bullet is a GameObject, I can use a prefab like that?

Comment: No. Try read this http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html You will need to get the component.

Comment: this answer seems to be what you need, although i would probably create a SetTarget function in the Bullet Script to use from the tower Script instead of setting the variable directly. You might want to accept the answer to encourage people to help in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are overcomplicating things, in that you seem to want to steer the bullet. I don't know how your turret works, but most turrets I have seen in games will start following the target when it's in view, and then start shooting at it when it's close enough.

Pseudo-ish, something like this:

```cs
void Update () {
    if ( canSeeTarget() ) {
        rotateToTarget();

        if ( targetInRange() ) {
            startShooting();
        }
    }
}
```